# How to Uninstall modules in Magento 2 using composer?

Tags: module, magento-2.0, composer, uninstall

How to Uninstall modules "ub data migration" in Magento 2 using composer

Answer (score 9):

You can uninstall a module through composer if it was installed using composer. If yes then issue command:

```
php bin/magento module:uninstall -r <Vendor>_<Module>
```

-r flag removes module data. 
then issue:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

If module was not installed through composer:

- remove the module directory `app/code/<Vendor>/<Module>`
- drop module database tables (if it created any)
- remove entry from core_config_data and setup_module tables

Run command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: Glad it helped, please accept the answer if found useful.

Comment: Thank you for answering this. If you could kindly help me understand When does one use composer remove <module_name >?